# Как делать микс левого и правого канала в Swift3?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3

Пишу мобильное приложение. Как в Xcode Swift3 сделать такое?

Трек-А(stereo) -> Трек-А(mono) -> Левый канал Трека-C

Трек-B(stereo) -> Трек-B(mono) -> Правый канал Трека-C

И в финале сохранить Трек-С как отдельный микс. 
Есть код который добавляет Стерео треки в композицию, но как его изменить для моего случая?

```
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    let compositionAudioTrack1 = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    let avAsset1 = AVURLAsset.init(url: url1, options: nil)
    let audioTrack1 = avAsset1.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]
    do {
        try compositionAudioTrack1.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset1.duration), of: audioTrack1, at: kCMTimeZero)
    } catch {
    }
```

Можно выставить громкость

```
    audioTrack1.preferredVolume = 1
```

А как сделать что-то типа:

```
    audioTrack1.pan = -1
```

Буду рад любой помощи, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Возможно и не подойдет, но гляньте на [AudioKit.io](http://audiokit.io/)

Очень легкая работа с аудио, широкий функционал (и снова же, очень легкий в работе). Пример кода:

```
let leftPanNode = AKPanner(leftNode, pan: -1)
let rightPanNode = AKPanner(rightNode, pan: 1)
let mix = AKMixer(leftPanNode, rightPanNode)
```